# How to get scrollview contentOffset?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a scrollview with 3 items spread evenly which a user can scroll though. I'm trying to come up with a way a user can tap a button and scroll to the new image in the scrollview. The issue is I don't know how to get the X value properly. This is my current code:

```
@IBAction func manualScrollButton(_ sender: Any) {
    switch pageControl.currentPage {
    case 0:
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 375, y: 0), animated: true)
    case 1:
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 750, y: 0), animated: true)
    case 2:
        print("3")

    default:
        print("none")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a reference to the image view you can look at its frame.

Comment: I have access to the scrollviews frame. The issue is I don't know how to get origin.X separately for every image

Comment: As I said, you need a reference to the image view.

Comment: Ok I got a reference. Can you give a code sample? Still kinda lost on how to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to a specific view (an image view in this case), then you need a reference to the view. Once you have that you simply use its `frame`.

```
@IBAction func manualScrollButton(_ sender: Any) {
    switch pageControl.currentPage {
    case 0:
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: someImageView.frame.origin.x, y: 0), animated: true)
    case 1:
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: otherImageView.frame.origin.x, y: 0), animated: true)
    case 2:
        print("3")

    default:
        print("none")
    }
}
```